# how can i increase scanning interval of BLE on Android?

Tags: intervals, ibeacon, network-scan

I'm playing with Radius Network, RedBearLab, estimote beacons.

and I want my app to receive RSSI much faster from beacons.

so I tried to increase Advertising interval. but my app wasn't listening anything from beacons.

I think I had to increase scanning interval as well. isn't it?

then how can i increase scanning interval on my app??

there is no such thing like control app for scanning interval.

Answer (score 3):

No Android iBeacon library supports that.

You would need to go straight to BLE library from Android BLE stack. That is using [BluetoothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) and  `startLeScan` directly.